# list of integer to comma delimited string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have tried this several ways and keep getting an error each time I try.

This is using .net 3.5 with asp.net(forms) and vb.net.

Examples:

```
Dim _registrations = New List(Of Integer)

Dim regList As String

Dim ListOfReg = _registrations.convertall(Of String)(Function(i As Integer) i.ToString())

regList = String.Join(",", ListOfReg.ToArray())
```

**Error message:**

`Overload resolution failed because no Public 'convertall' can be called with these arguments:
   'Public Function ConvertAll(Of String)(converter As System.Converter(Of Integer,String)) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)':
       Argument matching parameter 'converter' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Integer,String)' to 'Converter(Of Integer,String)'.`

Other attempt:

```
regList = String.Join(",", (_registrations.Select(Function(reg) reg.ToString()).ToArray()))
```

**Error message:**

`Public member 'Select' on type 'List(Of Integer)' not found.`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try to add 'Imports System.Linq' at the top of your vb file, and see if you still have errors.

Comment: I still get both errors after adding that.

Comment: I changed my answer, the new solution should work for 3.5.

Comment: On second thought, There is nothing wrong with your "other attempt", it works fine for me. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: It seems there was a scope issue with the variable due to it being a private variable in a class, once I moved the variable inside the scope of the function it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this should work , I guess it is the square brackets on the select?

.NET 3.5  solution

```
Dim integers As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
integers.Add(1)
integers.Add(2)
integers.Add(3)

Dim commas As String = String.Join(",", integers.[Select](Function(i) i.ToString()).ToArray())

MessageBox.Show(commas)
```

Below is the.NET 4.0 Solution

```
Dim integers As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
        integers.Add(1)
        integers.Add(2)
        integers.Add(3)


        Dim commas As String = String.Join(",", integers.ToArray)

        MessageBox.Show(commas)
```

Comment: you still have to convert the ints in strings, String.Join only accepts arrays of string - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c(v=vs.90))

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Comment: I ran the above code with options strict and option explicit on, is it failing for you?

Comment: @MSDN - Matthieu - Might want to check that bit of info. There is an overload that accepts an Object[] array that seems to do the job nicely, as I wrote almost the identical snipped to that PatFromCananda spun out (although in C#), and it works just fine...per MSDN, that particular overload just calls the ToString() method against each Object in the array...

Comment: @DavidW : that overload appeared only in net4.0+. It won't work for the OP.